# Is there an equivalent of DoEvents in Visual Studio macros?

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I've got a long-running macro, in which I write periodic messages to Output just so that the user know somethings happening. The problem is that the output doesn't get shown until the macro has finished (unless you have the Continue Waiting? dialog box open, strangely enough).

Is there anyway to 'flush' the event queue?

Comment: It's VB so does DoEvents not work?

Comment: @Preet, it's VBA (I think), and in any case I don't see the 'Application' object in intellisense, but maybe I'm missing some references?

Comment: Just use DoEvents, it is a statement in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you reference Windows Forms you can access Application.DoEvents as normal.

I have the main IDE responding to windows updates and closes in real time while the macro is still running with only

```
    DTE.SuppressUI = False
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

As such I suggest using a standard `DoEvents` & `Sleep(55)` loop for a 250 milliseconds or so when you want to ensure the UI is updated should do the trick, along with the `SuppressUI=False`.

Comment: Good idea, except that... it doesn't seem to make any difference :)